# Missing Browse button in PuTTY software

Tags: putty

I have downloaded PuTTY software to SSH into my AWS EC2 instance. The problem am facing is the browse button that am supposed to click on to access the private key is missing under the Auth category. I downloaded PuTTY from putty.org

Below is an image of where the browse button should have been.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpWEk.png)

I have uninstalled and reinstalled PuTTY but each time I open PuTTY, the browse button is missing.

Comment: This is [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). It would belong to [su]. Though I have answered this question there already: [Unable to browse private key in PuTTY](https://superuser.com/q/1752648/213663).

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at a picture from an older version of PuTTY.

The [Configuring PuTTY](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.78/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-privkey) documentation says that the "Private key file for authentication" is available in the **Credentials** panel (not the **Auth** panel).

Comment: Thanks, I was also facing the same problem.  I was looking in auth panel with newer version.